# What is the difference between PlayerView and StyledPlayerView in Android Exoplayer

Tags: android, kotlin, exoplayer

**PlayerView**

```
<com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.PlayerView
    android:id="@+id/exoplayerView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:controller_layout_id="@layout/layout_exoplayer_control_views"
    app:use_controller="true">
```

**StyledPlayerView**

```
<com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.StyledPlayerView
    android:id="@+id/exoplayerView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:controller_layout_id="@layout/layout_exoplayer_control_views"
    app:use_controller="true">
```

- What is the major difference between them.
- When to use which one and in what scenario.
- Customisation can be done in both using `app:controller_layout_id`, so why are there two different types of players

Comment: Did you find any update on this, If yes then please share here.

Comment: Please go through with this Medium link [ExoPlayer 2.12 - What’s new](https://medium.com/google-exoplayer/exoplayer-2-12-whats-new-e43ef8ff72e7), It will be helpful.